# Weird output from array

Tags: java, arrays

I've come across what appears to be an interesting bug...

For one of my classes, I need to write a program that simulates the old "x students going down a hallway closing lockers every x interval" scenario. However, an interesting twist is that the question requires there to be an equal number of students and lockers up to 100. So I decided to use an array, where the user input a number - which is then used to set up the array size, for-loop conditions, etc. etc... you get the picture, right?

Anyway, my code compiles, but when run it puts out something like:

```
[I@36ae2282
```

Someone (in another thread/question/whatever-you-call-it) stated that this is the physical location of the array in the system memory, and to get the actual numbers from the array the `.getNums()` method would be required. My problem is: the `.getNums()` method doesn't seem to exist in Java (perhaps it's part of another language?), so what is the next best alternative or solution?

Comment: Could you post the code where you 1) declare the array 2) initialise the array 3) print the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're printing out the int array, and that's a traditional array's .toString() representation. You may want to use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) for nicer looking output instead.

Answer (score 1):

To print the content of an array either iterate over each element in the array:

```
int[] array = new int[10];

for(int s : array) System.out.println(s);
// or
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) System.out.println(array[i]);
```

or use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29):

```
int[] array = new int[10];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

which will print something like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

> Anyway, my code compiles, but when run it puts out something like:
>
> ```
> [I@36ae2282
> ```

I assume you are trying to print the array like this:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
System.out.println(array);
```

`array` is an object, hence you are calling [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) of [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (`System.out`), which calls `toString()` on the passed object internally. The array's `toString()` is similar to [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)'s [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

So the output would be something like:

```
[I@756a7c99
```

where `[` represnts the depth of the array, and `I` refers to `int`. `756a7c99` is the value returned from [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) as a hex number.

Read also [`Class.getName()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).

Comment: Actually I was using `System.out.prinltln(array.toString());`, but thank you!